# Update multiple columns with Joining 2 tables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

Below is the code I am using for the update. The matching records between SRC and LKP table on the below condition are 31. But when I run the below update statement it's updating 200 records.Could you please suggest where could be the issue

```
UPDATE SRC  src      
  SET (src.A,src.B,src.C,src.D) = (select lkp.A,lkp.B,lkp.C,'1' 
                                   from LKP lkp
                                     inner join SRC
                                            ON src.id_1=lkp.id_1
                                           and src.CC=lkp.CC)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

- You have no `WHERE` clause so all columns are updated.
- You are referencing `SRC` in the subquery.

What I'm guessing you want is:

```
UPDATE SRC src      
  SET (src.A, src.B, src.C, src.D) =
        (select lkp.A, lkp.B, lkp.C, '1' 
         from LKP lkp
         where src.id_1 = lkp.id_1 and src.CC = lkp.CC
        )
  WHERE EXISTS (select 1
                from LKP lkp
                where src.id_1 = lkp.id_1 and src.CC = lkp.CC
               );
```

For performance, you want in index on `LKP(id_1, cc)`.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff.I ran this query for 5M records and it's Kept running. Is there a way to improve the performance of this query?

Comment: @Yogeeyadav . . . An index should solve that problem.  I added the suggestion to the answer.

Comment: Thank You. will Try on index